# Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component error when using Material UI in a package

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm building a package that is using Material UI, and when exporting it as a component and using it on another project i get the following error:

> × Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

> fix this problem.

I have material ui installed correctly on my package, not sure what the issue is.

**Note if i remove `<Typography></Typography>` the invalid hook error goes away, but i want to use material ui.**

**CommentBox.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import GifIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Gif";
type CommentType = {};

const CommentBox: React.FC<CommentType> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography
        className="title"
        style={{ paddingBottom: "20px" }}
        variant="subtitle1"
      >
        Owls are cool
      </Typography>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default CommentBox;
```

Maybe there is something wrong in my webpack config, or tsconfig ? I'll share

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts|tsx|js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I used your code with configs and i get no errors

Comment: How are you calling the component ? Can you share snapshot

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-star-n8h0v

Comment: hmmmmm. idk whats the issue, but material u isn't packaging correctly. I have to tinker with it some more.